# Method crashes server (homested; laravel)

Tags: php, crash, homestead

I'm using homestead. And I have this code

```
$researches = Auth::user()->load(['researches' => function ($q)
    {
        $q->orderBy('situational', 'desc');
        $q->orderBy('id', 'asc');
        $q->with('research_type');
    }])->researches;

    $researches = FormatController::sort($researches);
    dd($researches);
```

When I run this, the page loads endlessly and it ends with "gateway - timeout" and I have to restart homestead because nothing works anymore.

It crashes after running the sort-method in the FormatController. It looks like this:

```
public static function sort($values, $key = 'id')
{
    $sorted = [];
    foreach ($values as $v)
    {
        $sorted[$v->$key] = $v;
    }
    return $sorted;
}
```

I don't know why it crashes. This method is used several times before this part of the code and it works just fine.

If I die-dump right before the return statement, I get the array that I wanted

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say crash, do you mean like the web server itself crashes (i.e. Apache segfault) or PHP generates a Fatal error?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure. It loads for quite some time, gives me an "gateway - timed-out" error and then every page I try to load does the same (though they worked before I ran the script from above).

Comment: $sorted[$v->$key] = $v; What are you doing here?

Comment: I use the 'id'-attribute of the researches as a key to an array. This way I can access my researches like '$researches[$anyResearchId]'. If I wouldn't do this, the keys would just start with 0 and count up. Thus, I couldn't access specific researches

Comment: If I don't use `Auth::user()->load` and instead use `User::with` it works. I have no idea why, because `Auth:user()` ist just the user object, exactly like the one I get with `User::find(id)`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have no idea why but I found the solution:

Somewhat after this script I posted I typed this:

```
<? $research_type = 0; ?>
```

I changed it to

```
<?php $research_type = 0; ?>
```

That worked for me. Anyone knows why?